# Parsing error for date field

Tags: java

I want to parse a date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format to `YYYYMMDD`. If I use the following function, it returns me a `YYYYMMDD` format but with a different DD. i.E: `2013-05-16` BECOMES `20130515`

Apologies for sounding illiterate :) I am new to Java.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
String TestDate=yyyymmddParser.format(oLifEExtension.TestDate().getTime());
                    sb.append(TestDate)
```

Comment: How do you construct the date parser?

Comment: Sounds like you might be encountering issues with the default locale. Maybe it uses a different time zone or day light savings setting than you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the Question was meant for `java.util.Date` (a date plus time-of-day) or a `java.sql.Date` (a date-only). In both cases, you should be using the modern java.time classes rather than the troublesome legacy date-time classes.

Some other `java.sql.Date` questions are linked as duplicates of this one. So I handle both classes (sql & util) here.

## `java.util.Date`

The legacy `java.util.Date` class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC. This means a date with a time-of-day. The trick is that your input string is for a date-only value. You can first parse your string as a date-only value, then assign a time-of-day if desired.

Your input string complies with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of YYYY-MM-DD. The java.time classes default to the standard formats when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2013-05-16" ) ;
```

For a time-of-day, you probably want the first moment of the day. Do not assume the first moment is `00:00:00`. In some time zones an anomaly such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) may cause a day to start at a different time such as `01:00:00`. To account for such anomalies, we must specify a time zone in determining the first moment of the day.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Apply that zone in asking java.time to determine the first moment of the day. We produce a `ZonedDateTime` object as the result.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

If you desire a specific time of day, apply a `LocalTime` object. Keep in mind that your time-of-day may not be valid on that particular date for that particular zone. For example, you may be specifying a time-of-day occurring during a DST cutover. In such a case, the `ZonedDateTime` class has a policy for adjusting to accommodate. Be sure to read the documentation to understand that policy and the resulting behavior.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 0 ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;  // Time-of-day may be adjusted as needed.
```

## `java.sql.Date`

No need to use `java.sql.Date`. That class is replaced by `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

JDBC drivers that comply with JDBC 4.2 can deal directly with java.time types by calling:

- [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-)
  myPrepStmt.setObject( … , myLocalDate ) ;
- [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-)
  LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class );

For presentation of the `LocalDate` to the user, generate a String for display in your user-interface. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` to automatically localize. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

You can go the other direction as well, [parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) an input string to get a date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Trap for the exception thrown if the user’s input is faulty or unexpected.

```
try{ 
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
    myPrepStmt.setObject( … , ld ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … // Handle the error condition of faulty/unexpected input by user.
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

A `SimpleDateFormat` should be capable of achieving what you're after.  Be very careful with the format marks, `D` and `d` mean different things

```
String oldDateString = "2013-05-16";
System.out.println(oldDateString );
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(oldDateString);
System.out.println(date);
String newDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(date);
System.out.println(newDateString);
```

(Also, beware of `Y` and `y` :P)

This outputs

```
2013-05-16
Thu May 16 00:00:00 EST 2013
20130516
```

For me...