# Parsing the date, and converting to DATE for MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

So I am using DateFormat to convert a date (that I parsed form a CSV) to **YYYY-MM-DD format**, so I can INSERT it into a MYSQL column which is in DATE format.

I am using DateFormat, but my date output keeps coming out like this:

```
Mon Dec 29 00:00:00 CST 2014
Tue Dec 30 00:00:00 CST 2014
Tue Dec 30 00:00:00 CST 2014
Tue Dec 30 00:00:00 CST 2014
Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 CST 2014
```

How can I convert this date to the format I am looking for?

```
DateFormat formatter;
Date date;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

date = formatter.parse(date_parsed[0].toString());
System.out.println("DATE=" + date);
```

Comment: When you parse with `DateFormat` the date syntax you specified will be used to process the input strings but has nothing to do with the output. You simply used the `date` instance in output which means a `date.toString()` call and this uses a default format for dates. Try to use `System.out.println(formatter.format(date));` to output your date in your own format.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Parsing error for date field](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17225948/642706)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
String dateStr = "Tue Dec 30 00:00:00 CST 2014";
Date date = formatter.parse( dateStr );
formatter.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
String newDate = formatter.format( date );
System.out.println("DATE=" + newDate);
```

Output :

```
DATE=2014-12-30
```